# Batch variable concatenation for loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to create a for loop, that outputs a certain range of responses.

Using the following works fine:

```
echo Node1:
dashd-cli masternodelist status 123.123.123.100
echo.
echo Node2:
dashd-cli masternodelist status 123.123.123.200
echo.
echo Node3:
dashd-cli masternodelist status 123.123.123.300
```

OUTPUT:

Node01:
{
    "123.123.123.100" : "ENABLED"
}

Node02:
{
    "123.123.123.200" : "ENABLED"
}

Node03:
{
    "123.123.123.300" : "ENABLED"
}

I'm now trying to create a for loop that checks through a list of nodes:

```
cls
@echo off
set nodeCount=7
set Node1="111.111.111.111:1111"
set Node2="222.222.222.222:2222"
set Node3="333.333.333.333:3333"
set Node4="444.444.444.444:4444"
set Node5="555.555.555.555:5555"
set Node6="666.666.666.666:6666"
set Node7="777.777.777.777:7777"

for /L %%C in (1,1,%nodeCount%) do (
echo Node%%C:
dashd-cli masternodelist status %Node1%
)
```

The above method lists the Node1 IP up to seven times, how can I make it loop through the list of nodes? I'm well aware of the %%C but I simply don't know how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `delayedexpansion` and use `!node%%C!`:

```
cls
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nodeCount=7
set Node1="111.111.111.111:1111"
set Node2="222.222.222.222:2222"
set Node3="333.333.333.333:3333"
set Node4="444.444.444.444:4444"
set Node5="555.555.555.555:5555"
set Node6="666.666.666.666:6666"
set Node7="777.777.777.777:7777"

for /L %%C in (1,1,%nodeCount%) do (
echo Node%%C:
dashd-cli masternodelist status !Node%%C!
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!